# Save desktop window state in Lubuntu

Tags: openbox, lxde, lubuntu

Is there a way to save state of opened windows before restarting the computer? I use `lxsession` and `openbox`. I found this in openbox manual pages:

```
--sm-save-file <FILE>
        Specify file to load a saved session from.
```

But I still have no idea how to **save** the session.

Comment: I'm guessing you'll need a session manager to remember which programs are running at the time of shutdown and the sizes and positions of application windows. I don't think `lxsession` does this. I remember xfce4 having the ability to save sessions. But I don't know whether running `xfce4-session` will complicate matters. If you're adventurous, you can try `sudo apt-get install --no-install-recommends xfce4-session`. There's another q-n-a you may want to look at: http://superuser.com/questions/188182/what-session-manager-should-i-use

Comment: What do you need to remember: just size and position, or the state of the program?